# Is there a way to describe a repeating pattern in substitution?

Tags: substitute

I have multiple numbers in lines of 16, for example

```
  $02 c, $3f c, $fe c, $01 c, $ff c, $06 c, $00 c, $f8 c, $06 c, $1f c, $fe c, $00 c, $7f c, $8c c, $00 c, $fc c,
```

with pattern `[$][0-9][0-9]\s@,` and I need to substitute those lines by grouping the numbers in set of four and adding `group` after each group, like

```
 $02 $3f $fe $01 group $ff $06 ...
```

Is there a short way to do this, or I have to copy and paste same pattern four times in the `:s` command ?

Edit: the pattern should be: `\$\x\x c,`, thanks DJMcMayhem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right. `[$][0-9][0-9]\s@,` won't match the hex digits (such as `3f`), and it seems like there's a `c` after each number, not an `@`. Don't you mean they match this pattern?

```
[$][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\sc,
```

or even simpler

```
\$\x\x c,
```

But anyway, on to your main question. Yes, you can repeat a pattern without having to type it out multiple times. For example:

```
\(foo\)\{3}
```

will match "foo" repeated 3 times. I'd recommend reading through [quantifiers on vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy).

In your specific example, I'd recommend two regexes. One to remove the "c"s:

```
:s/ c,//g
```

Followed by a regex to add the "group" text:

```
:s/\v(\$\x\x ){4}/&group /g
```

Comment: For the first regex, I would recommend `%s/ c, \?/ /g`. That way you get a trailing space on the line, that is needed by the second regex. From the question, I assume that a trailing "group" is needed.